# React js: setState for each cells in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, datatable, setstate

So i'm trying to set style for every click on the table cells where when i click on one of the cell, it will highlight the cell on the first click and on the second click it will open up a pop ups. I tried to set the click count and classname using setstate but it highlighted and set the click count to the whole column of td. So far this is what i got, just a snippet:

```
class tableView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      countClicked: 0,
      selected: false
    };

handleClickOpen = (val) => {
  if (this.state.countClicked === 0) {
    this.setState({
      selected: true,
      countClicked: 1
    }))
  }
  if (this.state.countClicked === 1) {
    this.setState({
     selected: false
     countClicked: 0,
     setValueOfRow: val /*this is for pop ups*/
   }))


render(){
{data.map((c, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
         <td className={this.state.selected ? "activeCell" : "default" }>
             <button onClick={() => {
                this.handleClickOpen(c.name);
              }}>
             {c.name ? `${c.name}` : " ? "}
             </button>
         </td>
         <td className={this.state.selected ? "activeCell" : 
          "default" }>
             <button onClick={() => {
                this.handleClickOpen(c.age);
              }}>
             {c.age ? `${c.age}` : " ? "}
             </button>
         </td>
       <td className={this.state.selected ? "activeCell" : 
          "default" }>
             <button onClick={() => {
                this.handleClickOpen(c.email);
              }}>
             {c.email ? `${c.email}` : " ? "}
             </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
}
```

Comment: If you want individual states for each cell, you need an array of states. A single variable can obviously not store more than one cell's state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the "selected" state as an array of booleans each representing the selected state of each cell:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: new Array(this.props.data.length).fill(false)
    };
}
```

Also your data array is empty so no cells will render. I Am assuming that the data comes from the props here.

Then in `render()` you can use:

```
render(){
{this.propes.data.map((c, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
         <td className={this.state.selected[i] ? "activeCell" : "default" }>
             <button onClick={() => {
                this.handleClickOpen(i);
              }}>
             {c.name ? `${c.name}` : " ? "}
             </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
}
```

Note: Pass `i` into `handleClickOpen()` and toggle class with `this.state.selected[i]`

And then in `handleClickOpen()`:

```js
handleClickOpen = (index) => {
   let newSelected = this.state.selected;
   newSelected[index] = !newSelected[index];
   this.setState({
      selected: newSelected
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the selected state works but how do i make it so that the other columns not affected when i clicked  on the cell?

Comment: Instead of checking for `this.state.selected` and toggling class based on that, check for `this.state.selected[i]`

Comment: Sorry i probably wasn't clear with my question, i followed your example and its working fine except for when i click on one of the cell in column 'name', the other columns in the same index e.g age, email etc with the same toggle function also highlighted the cells. is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Ohhh in that case you will need to store your `selected` state as a 2D array.

Comment: In all honesty it’s impossible to give a more specific answer without knowing how you implemented the cols. Maybe opening another question would help you more as you can post your code

Comment: thank you for helping me out :) i will try to store the state in 2D array